# How can we received a image file from imageToUpload.Source and passed into another method

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms-4

How to receive a 'photo' displayed under `<Image x:Name="imageToUpload" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40"/>` and pass to a variable in Xamarin Forms ? I am getting the file/image at this line  `var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(....` would need to passed into `RegisterSave_OnClicked()` method and further save into SQLite database

[image]

```
 var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Pictures",
                    Name = "test.jpg",
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
                    CompressionQuality = 75,
                    CustomPhotoSize = 5,
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                });
```

//Register button save code given below:

```
public async void RegisterSave_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = (from y in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(y => y.Email == playerEmail) select y).Count();
            if(count!=0)
            {
                var updatePlayer = (from y in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(y => y.Email == playerEmail) select y);
                foreach (var update_Player in updatePlayer)
                {
                    update_Player.FullName = fullNameEntry.Text;
                    update_Player.Mobile = mobileEntry.Text;
                    // code continues here .......
                    // assuming conn is an SQLiteConnection
                    conn.Update(update_Player);   
                }               
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
            }
            else
            {
                PlayerDetails playerDetails = new PlayerDetails();
                playerDetails.FullName = fullNameEntry.Text;
                playerDetails.Mobile = mobileEntry.Text;
                // code continues here .......
```

[image]

Comment: @Lucas Zhang - MSFT - No I am not able to solve it yet. I have tried as as follow in `RegisterSave_Onclick()` ...`byte[] imageArray =    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
  file.Dispose();
  return memoryStream.ToArray();
}`

Comment: Also it says `file` doesn't exist in context

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have set a break point at `var imageArr = ReadFully(imageStream); `and it is somehow returning null ie byte [0], could you please advise why its returning as null. I can see the imageStream has got the image with length 4869 ( see the screen shot attached in the question )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the imageSource to database , we can convert it to a byte[] array .

```
public  byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

`MediaFile` has `GetStream().`

You could use this to the Stream and then convert that to a byte[]. Here is one way to do that:

1.define a stream in your contentPage

```
Stream imageStream;
```

And init it after you take the photo .

```
imageStream = file.GetStream();
```

And call it when you click the button

```
var imageArr= ReadFully(imageStream );
```

Comment: If we straight away use in RegisterSave_OnClick() like and assign your code to byte [] imageArray Will this work?

Comment: Yes of course, set the `file` as property of the contentPage .

Comment: Ok, now  in this line`ReadFully(image.Source)`,  image doesn't exist in context.

Comment: image is the imageToUpload in your project.

Comment: I have tried that first, `var imageArr = ReadFully(imageToUpload.Source);` now it gives ...`Argument 1 Cannot convert from Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource to System.IO.Stream

Comment: Thank you, now the error has gone, I have added the `get, set` in PlayerDetails class like this `public byte[] myImage { get; set; }`  and received the like in Register_OnSave like `var imageArr = ReadFully(imageStream);
                playerDetails.myImage = imageArr;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197735/discussion-between-soccerway-and-lucas-zhang-msft).

Comment: Zhang I have saved the image into the database as you suggested, but I got a doubt it being properly saved in database. The reason is that when i tried to display  back the saved image into some page, it is not displaying. Could you please have a look at this question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434077/images-saved-in-database-are-not-displaying-in-the-home-xaml-page-in-xamarin-for`, I am getting the PlayerImage is `0` `byte[0]` while setting a break point. Could you please have a look on the issue.

Comment: Zhang: I have to put this line of code `var imageArr= ReadFully(imageStream );` at the beginning of `RegisterSave_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)` function. Now receving the byte here.