# Images saved in database are not displaying in the Home.xaml page in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app `Home.xaml` are not displaying the image back after saving in database. While debugging I could see, `bytes[]` are displaying at PlayerImage against the player. In the xaml, I have `Source="{Binding PlayerImage}"` but couldn't figure the reason for not displaying. Are the bytes displaying correct at the break point ?

// Home.xaml

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="playerTemplate">
            <ContentView>
                <StackLayout  Margin="5,5" BackgroundColor="#584961">
                    <Image x:Name="{PlayerImage}" Source="{Binding PlayerImage}" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" Font="Bold,18" TextColor="White"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Mobile}" Font="Bold,13" TextColor="White"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SoccerPosition}" Font="Bold,13" TextColor="White"/>
                    <Button Text="Remove Player"  Clicked="DeleteButton_OnClicked" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50"  TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#d6b947"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout Margin="5">
        <CollectionView x:Name="collectionview"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource playerTemplate}">
            <!--span here decides the number of items shows in one line. Now is 3 items one line-->
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

// PlayerDetails.cs

```
public byte[] PlayerImage { get; set; }
```

//Home.xaml.cs

```
public void DisplayDetails()
        {
            List<PlayerDetails> details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < details.Count; i++)
            {
                players.Add(details[i]);
            }

        }
```

[image]

// Added my PlayerDetails.cs class also

```
public class PlayerDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        public byte[] PlayerImage { get; set; }

    string fullname;
        string mobile;
        string soccerposition;
        string email;

        public PlayerDetails()
        {

        }

        [Ignore]
        public Image Image
        {
            get
            {
                var image = new Image();
                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(PlayerImage));
                return image;
            }
            set
            {

               //PlayerImage = Convert.ToByteArray(value.Source);
               //Bitmap.FromStream(inStream);
            }
        }


        public string FullName
        {
            set
            {
                if (fullname != value)
                {
                    fullname = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FullName"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return fullname;
            }
        }

        public string Mobile
        {
            set
            {
                if (mobile != value)
                {
                    mobile = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Mobile"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return mobile;
            }

        }
        public string SoccerPosition
        {
            set
            {
                if (soccerposition != value)
                {
                    soccerposition = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SoccerPosition"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return soccerposition;
            }
        }
        public string Email
        {
            set
            {
                if (email != value)
                {
                    email = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Email"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return email;
            }

        }

       //public ImageSource Source { get; internal set; }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

Comment: first, a byte[] is not a valid ImageSource.  Second, `byte[0]` means that your array is 0 length, which means your image data is not being loaded.  Finally, storing images in the database is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, from the `List<PlayerDetails> details` how can we get the bytes and then convert into image, find a code to convert `public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}`

Comment: this will be much easier if you store your images in the file system and then store the paths in the db.  Then you can just use the fiel path for the image source binding.  But as I mentioned earlier, your PlayerImage property appears to be an empty array, so I would first figure out why that is happening.

Comment: Thanks I will check why it is storing as an empty array

Comment: @Jason Now I am successfully saving `bytearray` into SQlite database. Now how can I convert bytearray back into an Image and then pass into `Source="{Binding PlayerImage}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load an Image from a byte[] array in the Xamarin.Forms, you can try the following code:

c# code:

```
byte[] bitmapData = ...;
ImageSource imageSource= ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bitmapData));

PlayerImage.Source = imageSource;//binding in code
```

The xaml code:

```
<Image x:Name="PlayerImage"  WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25"/>
```

Or binding in xaml

```
<image Source="{Binding imageSource}"/>
```

Note：

1. I found the `x:Name="{PlayerImage}"` is not correct.
   It's should be:  `x:Name="PlayerImage"` not `x:Name="{PlayerImage}"`
2. you only need to use one way of the following binding methods:

   ```
    PlayerImage.Source = imageSource;// in code
   ```

And

```
 <Image x:Name="PlayerImage" Source="{Binding imageSource}" />
```

**Update:**

You can try to make use of a Converter derived from IValueConverter which could create the image back based on the byte array.

ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter.cs

```
public class ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource retSource = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
            var stream = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
            retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
        return retSource;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

PlayerDetails.cs

```
 public class PlayerDetails
  {
    // other fields

    public byte[] PlayerImage { get; set; }
  }
```

xaml(`a usage example`):

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <myformapp1:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImage" 
/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

 <StackLayout Margin="5">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding YoudataList}"> <!--changd to your dataList-->
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"  
                           x:Name="PlayerPic"
                           Source="{Binding PlayerImage, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="test1" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="test2"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: This is my Home.page.cs code to display players ..`List<PlayerDetails> details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < details.Count; i++)
            {
                players.Add(details[i]);
                byte[] byteImage = details[i].PlayerImage;
                PlayerImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteImage));

            }` and following is my Home.xaml to display `<Image x:Name="{PlayerImage}" Source="{Binding PlayerImage}" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25"/>`

Comment: It says ` PlayerImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteImage));` doesn't exist in context

Comment: I have added my `PlayerDetails.cs` class as well.

Comment: Could you have a look please

Comment: Now it says `image.Source = imageSource;`  ...image doesn't exist in context

Comment: Thanks Jessie, still not working, as advised I have udpated the Home.xaml`<Image x:Name="PlayerImage" Source="{Binding imageSource}" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25" />`

Comment: It says 'PlayerImage` doesn't exists in context. Is that `public byte[] PlayerImage { get; set; }` get, set method in PlayerDetails.cs causing the problem ?

Comment: You just need use one way to binding as I mentioned in the `note`, You can try to delete `Source="{Binding imageSource}"` in `xaml`

Comment: You can try to use another variable name instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197807/discussion-between-jessie-zhang-and-soccerway).

Comment: `I have created a new `public Image PlayerPic { get; set; }` method in PlayerDetails.cs  ``

Updated the Home.xaml with ` <Image x:Name="PlayerPic" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25" />`

In the code updated as like, still not looking good. 

for (int i = 0; i < details.Count; i++)
            {
                players.Add(details[i]);
                byte[] byteImage = details[i].PlayerImage;
                ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteImage));
                PlayerPic.Source = imageSource;//binding in code
            }`

Comment: Could you please check the `Home.xaml` given in the question. In my constructor I have following `players = new ObservableCollection<PlayerDetails>();
            collectionview.ItemsSource = players;`  Then the fetched records from database are added to `players.Add(details[i]);` in the code.

Comment: What should i need to give at this line...`<myformapp1:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImage"/>`

Comment: Awesome help JessieZhang and the `ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter` really works. Last night I managed to get the image displayed in my page from database