# How to convert byte array to image from web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin

My API converts many images to Byte Array and returns the Bytes, but I can't converting again to image. I intend to display in some listview all images from my API.

I tried this but I can't get any image, I was trying to get at least one.

```
        var url = "https://appmaragogi.com.br/api/Files/Upload?Id=ChurrascariaEstreladoMar";

        Byte[] imageAsBytes = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).Result;

        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
        teste.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream1; });
```

I'd like to show all images in list view, or a way to get all images

i'm using a Image in Xaml to show the Image

Comment: are you positive that your byte[] is valid image data?  Try writing it to a file and testing with an image viewer.

Comment: Do you know if the data you receive includes header information? if so you should probably also know the image/file type (jpeg, png,...etc.). If they're raw pixel bytes then you can easily copy the array to an image object

Comment: You just return byte array and file type (media type) from controller and on UI (MVC) side, you will need to show the image based on fie type

Comment: My byte[] contains multiple image data, and i set the MediaTypeHeaderValue for jpeg

Comment: if your data contains multiple images, then you need to have some mechanism to tell where each one starts/stops and save them separately.  You can't just create a stream and expect Forms to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make use of a Converter derived from `IValueConverter` which could create the image back based on the byte array.

You can refer to my thread of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434077/images-saved-in-database-are-not-displaying-in-the-home-xaml-page-in-xamarin-for/57455100#57455100):

The main code is as follows:

ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter.cs

```
 public class ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
 {
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    ImageSource retSource = null;
    if (value != null)
    {
        byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
        var stream = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
        retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
    }
    return retSource;
}
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

ImagesModel.cs

```
public class ImagesModel
{
   // other fields

   public byte[] PlayerImage { get; set; }
 }
```

xaml(a usage example):

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <myformapp1:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImage" />
</ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout Margin="5">
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding YoudataList}"> <!--changd to your dataList-->
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"  
                       x:Name="PlayerPic"
                       Source="{Binding PlayerImage, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="60" 
                       WidthRequest="60" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                       Text="test1" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1" 
                       Text="test2"
                       FontAttributes="Italic" 
                       VerticalOptions="End" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that only what you need is to save it in a local file, the only thing you have to check is that the format of the image in byte array is fine

```
File.WriteAllBytes(nameLocalFile, imageAsBytes);
```

Comment: I use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) to save in local file but none image has been saved