# Xamarin Image not loading from a given local machine path

Tags: android, image, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am storing a picture and binding it's path to a property called ImageUrl. when the url is set, the image in the form does not load. what could be the problem ? here is some code

```
    public class ImageRecord{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public void SetImage( string path) {

        ImagePath = path;

        var bitmap = ImageSource.FromFile(ImagePath );

        Image = new Image() {
            Source = bitmap,
            Margin = new Thickness(10)
        };
    }
```

Here is the designer in XAML

```
               <Image Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="80" x:DataType="DataObjects:ImageRecord">
                 <Image.Source>
                   <FileImageSource File="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                 </Image.Source>
               </Image>
            </Grid>
```

I also tried to set the `Source="the path of the image"` directly from the Image tag but no good.
The image is downloaded as byte[], and then is stored on the device(Android).

Comment: `am storing a picture` Ok. You? How? Or your app?  `and binding it's path` Please tell which full path that would be. Tell all in your post.

Comment: what specifically is "local machine path"?  Is this a path that the Android device will have access to at runtime?

Comment: @Jason yes it is a path that I am storing the image in on my android device

Comment: @blackapps  huh ?? I have a function the takes an array of bytes, and stores it as an image file (bmp).

Comment: is this an image that is added to your project bundle as an embedded resource?  Or is it an image that you are downloading at runtime?

Comment: @Jason it is downloaded

Comment: have you verified that the file is a valid image format and is not being corrupted when saved?  Where **specifically** are you downloading it?  Have you checked that the path is valid with `File.Exists()`?

Comment: Yes whenever I fetch the image back to store it's path in the object ImageRecord , i make sure that the path is valid, and then check for Existence of the file. using File.Exists.

Comment: "Where specifically are you downloading it?"
    var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var rootFolder = Path.Combine(documents, "Geo-Maps");
var userFolder = Path.Combine(rootFolder, "User");
var imagesFolder = Path.Combine(userFolder , "Images");

Comment: @ZZZ you are only posting code. But you should tell full path. `/storage/emulated/0/.........`

Comment: "/data/user/0/mapPlanner/files/Geo-Maps/Users/test/map1bmp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load an Image from a `byte[] array` in the Xamarin.Forms, you can try the following code:

c# code:

```
byte[] bitmapData = ...;
ImageSource imageSource= ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bitmapData));

PlayerImage.Source = imageSource;//binding in code
```

The xaml code:

```
<Image x:Name="PlayerImage"  WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25"/>
```

Or binding in xaml

```
<image Source="{Binding imageSource}"/>
```

In addition, you can also use [Xamarin Community Toolkit ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/bytearraytoimagesourceconverter) to achieve this, which is a converter that allows the user to convert an incoming value from byte array and returns an object of type ImageSource. This object can then be used as the Source of an Image control.

Please refer the following code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="MyLittleApp.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
             <xct:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>

        <Image Source="{Binding MyByteArray, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

You can also check the following threads:

[Images saved in database are not displaying in the Home.xaml page in Xamarin Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434077/images-saved-in-database-are-not-displaying-in-the-home-xaml-page-in-xamarin-for/57455100#57455100)