# How to bind picked images to the local SQLite database and display them on the page different from the page where Media picker buttons are? XAMARIN

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

Hi Xamarin GODS and GODDESSES. I am trying to find the solution to bind images selected with Media Picker (capture photo) and Media Gallery (pick photos), in order to save them on the local SQLite database and display them on the List View later on.
I have two buttons event handlers for taking photos from a camera and picking photos from a gallery. They are both similar methods (Also, is there a better method for those two methods to avoid stream?). However, I am unsure how to bind their results and display them in my List View and SQLite database. There is a save button on the page that saves all inputs made by users such as Title, experience, location, and images (which I am struggling with, how to save images?). When the save button is clicked, changes are presented in List view and SQLite.
It is quite easy to do that for text entry. However, how to do it for images???? I assume it should be somehow converted into bytes and arrays. But how? Please help!!!!
Below is my code with mentioned methods and how I am displaying it to the List View.
So basically, what I want to do is, have user's input in terms of EXPERIENCE, TITLE, LOCATION and IMAGE. Have it in my model Post class, save it to the SQ and display it in the list view.

XAML.CS

```
 namespace GetAroundCroatia
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class IznajmiIznajmljivaciPage1 : ContentPage
    {
        public IznajmiIznajmljivaciPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
  private async void takePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
            if (photo != null)
            {                
            var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
            resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);          
            }     
        }      
        private async void pickPhotos_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(3, MediaFileType.Image);
            if(results != null)
            {
                var imageList = new List<ImageSource>();
                foreach (var media in results.Files)
                {
                    var stream = await media.OpenReadAsync();
                    imageList.Add(ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream));
                }
                collectionView.ItemsSource = imageList;
            }     
        }
        private void save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {          
            PostClass post = new PostClass()
            {
                Experience = experienceEntry.Text,
                Title = titleEntry.Text,
                Location = locationEntry.Text,                                  
            };
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<PostClass>();
                int rows = conn.Insert(post);                    
                if (rows > 0)
                    DisplayAlert("Uspjesno", "Oglas Predan", "OK");
                else
                    DisplayAlert("Neuspjesno", "Oglas nije predan", "OK");
            }

            }
            catch (NullReferenceException nre)
            {
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GetAroundCroatia.IznajmiIznajmljivaciPage1">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="Save" Text="Predaj" Clicked="save_Clicked"/>        
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>                
                <Button x:Name="takePhoto" Text="Uslikaj" Clicked="takePhoto_Clicked"/>
                <Image x:Name="resultImage"/>                
                <Button x:Name="pickPhotos" Text="Odaberi iz galerije" Clicked="pickPhotos_Clicked"/>               
                <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding .}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
                <Label Text="Opci Podaci"/>
                <Entry x:Name="titleEntry"
                       Placeholder="Title"/>     
                <Entry x:Name="experienceEntry"
                       Placeholder="Opis"/>
                <Entry x:Name="locationEntry"
                       Placeholder="Unesi Lokaciju"/>
                <Entry x:Name="raspolozivostEntry"
                       Placeholder="Odaberi Raspolozivost"/>
                <Entry x:Name="dostavaEntry"
                       Placeholder="mogucnost dostave"/>           
                <Entry x:Name="soferopcijaEntry"
                       Placeholder="Mogucnost Vozac" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>      
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Model POST CLASS:

```
public class PostClass
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Experience { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
```

List View XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="PostListViewOglasi"
                  ItemTapped="PostListViewOglasi_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Experience}" FontSize="15"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Location}" FontSize="15"/>  
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

List View XAML.CS:

```
 public OglasiListViewPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation)) 
            {
                conn.CreateTable<PostClass>();
                var posts = conn.Table<PostClass>().ToList();
                PostListViewOglasi.ItemsSource = posts;
            }
        }
        private void PostListViewOglasi_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedPost = PostListViewOglasi.SelectedItem as PostClass;
            if(selectedPost != null)
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new DetaljiPostOglasaPage1(selectedPost));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CapturePhotoAsync()` returns a `FileResult` object that has a file name and path.  You should just be able to store that path as a string in your db

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for the response. Do you mind writing a code on how I should relate the file path to my Post class and how to read (bind) mentioned path in the List View?  I am new to coding, and currently, I am stuck here. I can't figure out the solution on how to do it. And the project has significant importance

Comment: Just add a string property to your class and set it to the file path.  You can bind an image source to a path

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, Jason. I am going to do it now and will let you know we did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Media Picker (capture photo) and Media Gallery (pick photos)

What nuget do you used in your project?

And it is recommended that you use [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android) to achieve this.

You can get the `FullPath` of your image except the `stream` after you capture an image.

Please refer the following code:

```
async void CapturePhoto_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

        if (result != null)
        {
            var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

            resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

            string imagePath = result.FullPath;// get the fullpath and save to database
        }
    }
```

For saving your image to database , you can just add a new property ,for example:

```
  public string imagePath { get; set; }`
```

to your class `PostClass` and save the `imagePath`  to your database.

You can also use method  `MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync` to pick photos.

Please refer to the following code:

```
    async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
        {
            Title = "Please pick a photo"
        });

        if (result != null)
        {
            var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

            resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

            string path = result.FullPath;
        }
    }
```

**Note:**

> How to bind picked images to the local SQLite database and display
> them on the page different from the page

For how to load images from database, you can refer to the following thread:[Images saved in database are not displaying in the Home.xaml page in Xamarin Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434077/images-saved-in-database-are-not-displaying-in-the-home-xaml-page-in-xamarin-for/57455100#57455100) .

Comment: Hi Jessie, thanks a lot for the answer
I am using Xamarin Essential for photo capturing and  Xamarin.MediaGallery NuGet Package for picking multiple photos from the library. I am going to try it now and adjust my code as suggested. I will update you on my progress. Or ask the following question if something will be unclear. Many Thanks

Comment: Zhang. I added string imagePath to the full path on my capture photo code. Also, I added string imagePath to the Post Class. Moreover, to my list view, I added  <Image Source="{Binding imagePath}"/>. However, it is still unclear to me what should I put in my Save button event where I have  PostClass post = new PostClass() {
                Experience = experienceEntry.Text,
                Title = titleEntry.Text,
                Location = locationEntry.Text,
                imagePath = ?. 
What should I put imagePath to be equal in order to close the code?

Comment: Below are presented the changes which I made when following your suggestion. Please correct me if I did something wrong. And please suggest to me the solution for imagePath =?. I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now, struggling to find a solution. Many Thanks. Patrick

Comment: private async void takePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

            if (photo != null)
            {
                
            var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();

            resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                string imagePath = photo.FullPath;
            }
        }

Comment: POST CLASS:    public string imagePath { get; set; }

Comment: LIST VIEW:   <Image Source="{Binding imagePath}"/>

Comment: AND SAVE BUTTON WITH POST CLASS: private void save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            
            PostClass post = new PostClass()
            {
                Experience = experienceEntry.Text,
                Title = titleEntry.Text,
                Location = locationEntry.Text,
                imagePath. = WHAT TO ENTER HERE?
                };

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jessie Zhang and @ Jason, I found the solution. Thus, I am sharing it with others who could potentially encounter a similar problem. I declared the imagePath string outside the capture photo method and accessed it in my Capture photo method and in my Save button method. Below is a complete code on how I captured the photo, saved it in the local SQLite, and displayed it in my list view. Thanks for the help, guys.

```
public partial class IznajmiIznajmljivaciPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public IznajmiIznajmljivaciPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string imagePath;
    private async void takePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

        if (photo != null)
        {
            
        var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();

        resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            imagePath = photo.FullPath;
        }
    }

private void save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

        
        PostClass post = new PostClass()
        {
            Experience = experienceEntry.Text,
            Title = titleEntry.Text,
            Location = locationEntry.Text,
            imagePath = imagePath
            };


        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<PostClass>();
            int rows = conn.Insert(post);
                

            if (rows > 0)
                DisplayAlert("Uspjesno", "Oglas Predan", "OK");
            else
                DisplayAlert("Neuspjesno", "Oglas nije predan", "OK");
        }

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nre)
        {

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

POST CLASS:

```
 public string imagePath { get; set; }
```

LIST VIEW:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding imagePath}"/>
```