# How do I show an image from a database in .NET Maui ListView

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a table which has an image in one of the columns as a VARBINARY(MAX). I can get the image from EntityFramework - it comes out as a byte[].

How can I databind that image byte array so that it shows in a Maui ListView? I seem to be having trouble converting all the various data types to get it to show...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to make use of a Converter derived from `IValueConverter` which could create the image back based on the byte array.

You can refer to the following code:

**ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter.cs**

```
public class ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource retSource = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
            var stream = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
            retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
        return retSource;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item
  {
    // other fields

    public byte[] PlayerImage { get; set; }
  }
```

**A usage example**

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <myformapp1:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImage" 
/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

 <StackLayout Margin="5">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding YoudataList}"> <!--changd to your dataList-->
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"  
                           x:Name="PlayerPic"
                           Source="{Binding PlayerImage, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="test1" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="test2"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

For more informatin, you can check thread:[Images saved in database are not displaying in the Home.xaml page in Xamarin Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434077/images-saved-in-database-are-not-displaying-in-the-home-xaml-page-in-xamarin-for/57455100#57455100).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter` that is part of the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit.

Usage example:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         x:Class="CommunityToolkit.Maui.Sample.Pages.Converters.ByteArrayToImageSourceConverterPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Image Source="{Binding DotNetBotImageByteArray, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}" />

</ContentPage>
```

For more information see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/byte-array-to-image-source-converter).